OML Notebook SELECT columns from Database
In OML Notebook, how call SQL Select all columns from the Oracle Database table.
test_sentences = oml.sync(table = "CONFILE_1000")["TEXT"].pull() --- This is working fine but I need to read 4-5 columns from the same table, what would be the syntax?
I tried below one:
test_sentences = oml.sync(table = "CONFILE_1000")["TEXT","ID"].pull() --- did not work

Use the oml.sync() function with a query to select the desired columns:
import oml
test_sentences = oml.sync(query = "SELECT TEXT FROM CONFILE_1000")

This creates a proxy object called test_sentences containing the selected columns.

test_sentences = oml.sync(table = "CONFILE_1000")["TEXT"].pull() #Return type is list
test_sentences = oml.sync(query="select * from confile_1000 order by id").pull() #Return type is pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. If we remove pull then it would OML data Frame
